# How to upload video in react-native?

Tags: react-native, axios, fetch

Im want to upload video picked using "ImagePicker" to my server,The below code is not working?What's the Issue ?

```
const handleUploadVideo = (video) => {
console.log(video) //{path:"/storage/emulated/0/WhatsApp/Media/WhatsApp 
                     Video/VID-20201107-WA0004.mp4"
                     uri: "content://media/external/video/media/4264"
const data = new FormData();
data.append('file', {
  name: 'VID-20201107-WA0004.mp4',
  type: 'video/mp4',
  uri: video.uri,
});

fetch('https://staging-api.media.com/api/upload', {
  method: 'POST',
  body: data,
})
  .then((response) => response.json())
  .then((response) => {
    console.log('upload succes', response);
    alert('Upload success!');
    this.setState({photo: null});
  })
  .catch((error) => {
    console.log('upload error', error);
    alert('Upload failed!');
  });
```

};

When execute the code,no response,nothing happens

Comment: You need to tell *us* what the issue is. What happens when you try that code? Do you get error messages? What is printed in the console?

Answer (score -1):

```
const handleUploadVideo = (video) => {
console.log(video);
const data = new FormData();

data.append('file', {
  name: 'VID-20201107-WA0004.mp4',
  type: 'video/mp4',
  uri: video.uri,
});

fetch('https://staging-api/api/youtube/upload', {
  method: 'POST',
  body: data,
})
  .then((response) => response.json())
  .then((response) => {
    console.log('upload succes', response);
    alert('Upload success!');
  })
  .catch((error) => {
    console.log('upload error', error);
    alert('Upload failed!');
  });
};
```